# Copying the generated private ssh key into the .ssh folder beneath Jenkins

Tags: continuous-integration, jenkins

I'm having problems linking Jenkins to github.
I've generated ssh-public keys then added it to github.

Then I tried to copy the generated private ssh key into the .ssh folder beneath jenkins, but I cannot locate it anywhere on my hard drive.(Mac OS Mountain Lion)

Home directory of Jenkins is /Shared/Jenkins/Home

When I go under `cd /var/lib/`, the only folder I can see is postfix...
Don't get why I don't have Jenkins under `/var/lib/`

I've installed Jenkins by downloading a .pkg file from the official website.

Any ideas on how to add privated ssh keys into the .ssh folder beneath Jenkins?

Answer (score 2):

This should help you: http://colonelpanic.net/2011/06/jenkins-on-mac-os-x-git-w-ssh-public-key/

Comment: I already tried editing org.jenkins-ci.plist.
I've changed the Jenkins user into admin, which have authority through all the files.